# ElasticSearch profile API `time_in_nanoseconds` value higher than `took` time

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

I'm using the ElasticSearch profile API to help with a slow query.

When I read [the elasticsearch profiling docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/_profiling_queries.html#_literal_query_literal_section) it sounded like the `time_in_nanos` value for queries in the shards should be less than the total `took` time when running a profiling query.

However, I got the following results back:

```
{
  "took": 109695,
   ...
  "profile": {
    "shards": [
       {
         "searches": [
           {
             "query": [
               {
                 "type": "BooleanQuery",
                 "time": "1550750.786ms",
                 "time_in_nanos": 1550750786163
                 ...
               }
             ]
           }
         ]
       }
       ...
     ]
  }
}
```

So, I see that the query `took` `109695` ms ~= `109` seconds which seems about right.

However, I see the `1550750786163` value for `time_in_nanos` which corresponds to over `20` minutes. This does not match the `took` value. The `curl` command took about 2 minutes so the `took` time seems accurate while the `time_in_nanos` time does not seem accurate.

**What is the correct way to interpret the `time_in_nanos` value in an ElasticSearch profile query?**

ES version: 5.6

Comment: When leveraging profiling, you need to be aware that this adds a fair amount of overhead, so what you see in the profiling results should be considered relative (e.g. to other query parts), not absolute times.

Comment: @Val - I know that profiling slows down the query (definitely not using in production). However, `took` should be `<=` than `time_in_nanos` in the *same* query, right? Or am I misunderstanding something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Elastic search Github repository, profile timings are a result of sampling. Because they are sampled, the raw timing numbers may not be accurate for large queries.

However, these numbers can be used to compare parts of the query with other parts of the query to determine the *relative* expense of the respective parts.

Source: https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/33489